# Insertinto database with xpath query and multiple xpath expressions

Tags: xpath, expression, mule

I am new to xpath and I'm trying to use multiple expressions with the "|" Separator, however when I have the configuration xml set to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <jdbc-ee:mssql-data-source name="MS_SQL_Data_Source" user="username" password="passcode" url="jdbc:sqlserver://DOMAIN\SQLEXPRESS:65183;databaseName=MULETEST" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="MS SQL Data Source"/>
    <jdbc-ee:connector name="Database" dataSource-ref="MS_SQL_Data_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
        <jdbc-ee:query key="InsertRecord" value="INSERT INTO databaseupdate(BuyerOrderNumber, OrderIssueDate) VALUES (#[xpath('//BuyerOrderNumber').text], #[xpath('//OrderIssueDate').text])"/>
    </jdbc-ee:connector>
    <flow name="Write_xml_file_to_databaseFlow1" doc:name="Write_xml_file_to_databaseFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\mule" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/Order/OrderHeader/OrderNumber|/Order/OrderHeader" doc:name="Splitter"/>
        <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="InsertRecord" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database" doc:name="Destination"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I get a NULLPointerException.  My confusion lies in xpath queries, how do I hardcode multiple expression paths, and associate that with the xpath query using the insert?
Thanks.

Comment: XPath requires the parentheses: `( /Order/OrderHeader/OrderNumber | /Order/OrderHeader )`.

Comment: hmm same problem, I get a null pointer exception on Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  
2. [Error: null pointer: xpath('//OrderIssueDate').text]
[Near : {... xpath('//OrderIssueDate').text ....}]
             ^
[
3. Execution of the expression "xpath('//OrderIssueDate').text" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
  org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:218

Comment: expression="(/Order/OrderHeader/OrderNumber | /Order/OrderHeader)" as the expression

Comment: i think its a problem with my mule database query

Comment: how do i retrieve the value of the second path in the database query